# MailGun and L5 Class 'GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle, mailgun

I am trying to use Mailgun with Laravel 5.0 and the inbuilt auth functionality.

When running `/password/email` I get `FatalErrorException in MailgunTransport.php line 79:
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Post\PostFile' not found`

This is part of my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
},
```

Could it be that the versions of Guzzle and Laravel don't work well together?

Downgrading guzzle to `~5.0` nets me 400 bad request errors.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as activating my account via email. By not having a verified account, it threw errors all over the place.

I also downgraded to Guzzle ~5.0 after checking for a Post file in the repo.

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade your guzzle by running this command in your command line

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.0
```